# unique constraint when column value is equal to false?

Tags: mysql

In mysql is it possible to have a unique constraint only when a value is false?

For example, I want a unique constraint on `Name` but only if `Archived = false`.

In other words I have a field `archived` which I'm using as a soft delete and deleting two things with the same name will result in a violation if I put the unique constraitn around Name and archived. hence wondering if the database can handle this type of unique constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Relevant Example

I think the only way to do this would be with Triggers, and Signals.
Just put your trigger for update and insert.

Relevant Example of Similar Approach From here: http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert_allow_only_one_active
     BEFORE INSERT ON example_tbl FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.active = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example_tbl 
               WHERE active=1 AND foreign_key_id=NEW.foreign_key_id) > 0
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type';
          END IF;
     END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_update_allow_only_one_active
     BEFORE UPDATE ON example_tbl  FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.active = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example_tbl
               WHERE id<>NEW.id AND active=1 AND foreign_key_id=NEW.foreign_key_id) > 0
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```

### Applied to your case

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert_allow_only_one_not_archived
     BEFORE INSERT ON example_tbl FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.archived = 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example_tbl 
               WHERE name=NEW.name) > 0
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: existing name exists and you are entering with archived = 0 (false)';
          END IF;
     END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_update_allow_only_one_not_archived
     BEFORE UPDATE ON example_tbl  FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF  NEW.archived = 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example_tbl 
               WHERE name=NEW.name) > 0
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    S SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: existing name exists and you are entering with archived = 0 (false)';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```

Finally, you may actually be interested in using the following statement in your SQL if you only want one NAME for archived = false, but unlimited for archived = true.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example_tbl  WHERE name=NEW.name AND archived = 0;
```